# How to implement dynamic page turning/curling with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I suspect most web developers are familiar with the Flash-based page curling transition to turn pages? ([Such as here](http://www.cluttermagazine.com/shop/magazines/issue13/index.php))

Can this be implemented, in a good way, with just simple HTML+CSS+JS?
(or any other 'native' browser languages, like SVG?)

My preferred library is jQuery, but any working JavaScript solution would be acceptable.

Comment: people who're not geeks loves that effect

Comment: The anyone who can update this question to have a working example/demonstration of the requested feature? The current link is broken, and the wayback machine archives barely load any part of the page