# Page Transition Like A Page Turning

Tags: jquery, html, css

Anyone know of any code/plugins for jquery that would transition the to the next page of a site with a animation akin to a page turning in a book? Thanks.

EDIT: Apparently I wasn't clear enough. I'm not looking for some gimmicky thing like: http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/

I'm looking to click a link on a page and have it transition to the next page with an animation that looks similar to turning the page of a book.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement dynamic page turning/curling with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702976/how-to-implement-dynamic-page-turning-curling-with-javascript)

Comment: Googling "jquery page turn" comes back with tons of results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page flip effect for HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613515/page-flip-effect-for-html5)

Comment: Sounds like: http://grasshopperpebbles.com/demos/index.php/bookflip/manual